# Antd floating icon in the tittle of Drawer

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to make an absolutely positioned element (an icon) to float inside an Antd Drawer title but it gets cut beyond the modal.

I have tried to give it infinite z-index in the div and in the Drawer prop but without success.

I am attaching a codesanbox so that I can explain my point and you can play around.

What am I missing?

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-in-drawer-title-antd-4-16-13-ofxr9?file=/index.css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found it!

In the end it was simpler than other approaches that I tried...
It is always tricky when you have to play with a new library. Anyway I updated the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-in-drawer-title-antd-4-16-13-ofxr9?file=/index.css:508-640) so you can see it working!

Here is the magic:

```
.ant-drawer-open .ant-drawer-content-wrapper {
  overflow: visible;
}

.ant-drawer-open .ant-drawer-content {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Is this what you want to achieve?](https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-in-drawer-title-antd-4-16-13-forked-qzv4x?file=/index.css)

If yes, just give a `position: relative` to the parent container :)

Comment: No, it is a good attempt but positioning is not the problem. The problem is that when you want half of the icon to be out of the Drawer (like if it was a tab) the part of the icon outside gets hidden. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

z-index will not work until and unless the position of that element is set. You are giving the z-index but not giving the position to the drawer. Please give `position: relative;` to the Drawer

Comment: Sorry, I tried that but it did not work. I added the class 'drawer' to the Drawer and set position relative but no success... Nice try though!